# Random effects vs fixed effects with balanced designs

Tags: random-effects-model

In my statistics lectures it is mentioned that for balanced data (same number of participants in each block), the results will be the same whether the model is fitted with factor A as a fixed effect or a random effect. For example:

```
lme(effort ~ Type, random = ~1|Subject)
```

will give me the same answer as

```
lm(effort~ Type + Subject)
```

By contrast, it is mentioned that with unbalanced data, the results will not be the same.

What is meant by 'same answer'. If I run both models I get two different outputs. What is the same?

Comment: Welcome to the site! Please note that signing posts is considered redundant here because the site engine automatically places your profile flair under your posts.

Answer (score 3):

With a simple, balanced design, you can build an anova table with sums of squares and mean squares - whether Subject is random or not. lm and lme give the same residual mean square error. But you would do a different F test for the significance of Type. In the fixed effect case, you use mean square (Type)/residual mean square. With a random effect, the F test is Type over Subject.

In an unbalanced design, lme estimates the effects and variance component differently from lm, so you get different results.